# How to plot functions and combine into one graph in Mathematica using a Table[Plot[ approach?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Here is an attempt to plot 2-c Exp[-t] for c=-3 to 3 by 1 in Mathematica.

```
Table[Plot[2 - c  Exp[-t], {t, 0, 1}], {c, -3, 3}]
```

I want these 7 plots to be combined into one image. The following gives an error message.

```
Show[{%, %%, %%%, %%%%, %%%%%, %%%%%%, %%%%%%%}]
```

How to do?  Another approach?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. As the most basic case, this will work:

```
Show[
 Table[Plot[2 - c Exp[-t], {t, 0, 1}], {c, -3, 3}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

But here's a cleaner one:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[2 - c Exp[-t], {c, -3, 3}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]